# Why is Linux's "sort -u" so much faster than Excel's

Tags: linux, excel, sorting

I tried finding unique records from an Excel file that had around 3 million records. (Sort & Filter > Advance > Unique Only). It took more than 4 hours and was still running. I tried interacting with it and it crashed. 
So I did sort -u in Linux and it did not even take 1 whole minute. 
Why is this so much faster than Excel's sort? 
PS, The machine with MSExcel had 12gb RAM, windows 10. Poor Linux thing had only 1 or 2 GB I think.

Comment: Hard to answer when we don't know anything about the file. Does it have formulas?

Comment: Please check your question. In one place you say that the Linux sort is faster, but later you say, "Why is this so much faster than Linux's sort?" Did you mean "than Excel's sort?" Unless you find somebody who's familiar with the source code for both programs, it's unlikely you'll get a definitive answer.

Comment: @Andreas No, it's only string data.

Comment: @JimMischel Yes, thank you. It indeed was a typo.

Answer (score -1):

As I know Linux sort version is a classic UNIX sort which is a part of GNU coreutils-6.9.90.

This is classic example of the standard **External R-Way merge** , to sort a data of size N bytes with a main memory size of M so it creates N/M runs and merges R at a time, the number of passes through the data is log(N/M)/log(R) passes.

**About Excel** I don't know for sure, but I would guess that they
use the same ones everyone else uses, converting the
characters to their character set numbers and sorting
them in numeric order by character set number if case
sensitive, or adding a constant like 32 to the upper case
numbers to make them equal to lowercase numbers if not
case sensitive.

If you want to create a special sort order,

```
   choose Tools>> Options >> Custom Lists
```

and create your own sort order. Then when you are ready to sort data, choose the
options button on the sort dialog box and select a custom list as an alternate sort key order.

As per my understanding in the linux sorting phase, it will chunks whole data into small pieces enough to fit in main memory then it will read, sort, and write out to a temporary file & then finally merge all sorted subfiles into single larger file. This may be reason which makes linux sort faster than excel sort

Comment: "I don't know for sure, but I would guess..." And that's all this "answer" is: pure speculation.